# Anyone can explain about MongoDB GridFS feature?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I am one of the MongoDB user.Unfortunately i heard about MongoDB GridFS feature but i am not sure When and where to use that feature or its necessary to use.If you might be using the feature then, i hope you guys can explain precisely about this feature.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd look into using GridFS if you needed to store large files in MongoDB.

Quote from the [MongoDB documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS) which I think sums it up well:

> The database supports native storage
>   of binary data within BSON objects. 
>   However, BSON objects in MongoDB are
>   limited to 4MB in size.  The GridFS
>   spec provides a mechanism for
>   transparently dividing a large file
>   among multiple documents. This allows
>   us to efficiently store large objects,
>   and in the case of especially large
>   files, such as videos, permits range
>   operations (e.g., fetching only the
>   first N bytes of a file).

There's also the GridFS specification [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Specification)

Comment: Note that the BSON size limit increased to 16MB as of MongoDB v1.7/1.8 .  If you need to store documents under this size, you could also consider storing binary objects directly as single documents.  There's a wiki page with some suggestions on [When to use GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/When+to+use+GridFS).